# ul li a background image issue while hitting back button on IE browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a a href inside Ul li.

This a is having background image as some red color , when i go to other page and hit back button 
i still have the same background image, how can i get rid of that.When i click anywhere on the page it goesaway.

```
<ul>
<li>
<a class="headerDD"> </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the link is still "selected", like you just clicked on it? If that's the problem, I don't think there's much you can do, but I'm hoping someone comes up with a solution :)

Comment: It is common behavior for a browser to 'remember' which link you last clicked on when using the Back button.

Comment: Define 'common behavior' :) I think it's just a matter of the browser caching the rendered page in memory or not. IE doesn't 'close' the page when you navigate away from it, so that when you click on the back button, the same page (with the same :active link) is brought back before your eyes straight from memory. Chrome, for example, doesn't do that, and usually reloads at least part of the page when you go back.

Comment: firefox is not behaving that way

a href has hover as different background image , that is getting selected on back button
this is happening only on IE

Comment: hi all , when i click on body anywhere else on page , its coming back to original state which is red background as image.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't super clear, so I'm not 100% sure what you want.  If you just want to change the color/background color, you can use the :visited attribute in CSS.

For example...

```
a:visited {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: the problem is , 

the intial background for that is red image , 
when i mouseover it changes to grey , i click that href to to some other page. Now i hit back button of browser and come back
to the initial page.

Now i have the grey image selected for that href.

Comment: @gov: maybe you could post your CSS so we can see what's going on?

Comment: here #headerMenuBar li:hover a, 
#headerMenuBar a:active, #headerMenuBar li.p7hvr a {
 background-image:url(http://cache1.allpostersimages.com/images/header/subNavOn.jpg);
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 background-position:top left;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

Comment: @jnpcl , the credit goes to you , when you asked for the code i started grabbing all code and fouund that

Answer (score 1):

try adding and removing class

using `addClass() and removeClass()` functions.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

On intial loading addClass with background red.

On click remove it and add class with grey

Or you can try adding css

http://api.jquery.com/add/